# Count of currently active jenkins agents

Tags: jenkins

Is there an easy way to get a count of how many agents are currently up? I know I can go to `www.myjenkins.com/computer/` to see the agents, but counting them manually is tedious.

Is there an API call or something I can run in the script console that just outputs the count for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sufix `computer/` with `api/json` and run some script on this response. Count the computers array or group by some one of his attributes, like `idle` or `offline`.

`https://www.myjenkins.com/computer/api/json`

[image: Json Sample]

Comment: To add to your (correct) answer, it turns out it's easy enough to either isolate by `totalExecutors` and do the math yourself (ie, divide by how many executors per agent), or grep the api results for the `displayName` of your agents and count that result.